# Do unused mysql tables affect the website performance?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to perform an optimization for my website, and would like to create new tables with prefix `old_` on the same database to hold thousands of old rows (since 2007) and keep only data that starts from year 2011. So PHP performs a query only for data that starts from year 2011 at original table.

Does the `old_table` that holds old data affect the performance?

Note: the `old_table` will be isolated (PHP won't access this table anymore).

Comment: really getting confused what's going on here, even my question got -1. really strange people still exist :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All tables use up internal resources of the database and make central database functions slower.

However usually this shouldn't be noticable.

They may use up some of your memory and they of course use up storage. As long as you don't have any concerns there I personally wouldn't care.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply, if you were in my choes; what would you do? or just i  ask what do you rocommend?

Comment: If you plan on using it later on I would leave it in the database. If after some time you notice you don't really need them I would remove them fromt the database after exporting them. If your database is small you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it CAN hurt performance, especially - as the above post mentioned - if you are low on RAM because it will mean more RAM is being used and if you are low on RAM this can cause all sorts of performance degradation.

For example, lets say you have **website_new** and unused **website_old** databases. If you had **innodb_buffer_pool_size** set to 3GB then you would need to increase that if the **website_old** is left sitting there. Or you will notice that **InnoDB buffer pool free** will be depleted because MySQL is buffering for both databases no matter usage.

Even with lots of RAM, keeping old DBs around will in general force you to increase a lot of your my.cnf config settings to maintain performance.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

They won't slow your db down considerably and in all likelihood its not even necessary to "archive" the old data. If you're using indexes on the tables properly then the whole purpose of the database is to be able to search thousands, millions, even billions or rows efficiently without much degradation.  I would leave them where they are. Moving the data to another table(s) is probably no performance enhancer if tables are properly indexed.

R